# url not defined. Refactor to new versions of angularfire, angular

Tags: firebase, undefined, firebase-storage, angularfire2, angular6

I have refactor problems because my code dosnt work to the new versions of angular and angularfire.

**Error**

The line:  upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL; is undefined.

**Code**

```
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
  // three observers
  // 1.) state_changed observer
  (snapshot) => {
    // upload in progress
    upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log(upload.progress);
  },
  // 2.) error observer
  (error) => {
    // upload failed
    console.log(error);
  },
  // 3.) success observer
  (): any => {

    upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL; //?!?!UNDEFINED
    upload.name = upload.file.name;
    this.saveFileData(upload);
  }
);
```

**Questions**

I had tried different solutions from stackoverflow but it dosnt really work. Most of the example is also more about how to retrieve the image but i want to set the variable upload.url to a value.

Another question:
I'm new to angular and web. Will it take long time to change it to firestore? The code is based on realtime firebase.

Comment: Have a look to this answer, in spite of being part of a component that manages upload and deletion of several pics, you’ll see easily how to upload a single image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769074/angularfire-upload-and-get-download-url/51805074#51805074

Answer (score 0):

To get the downloadURL, you have to call the [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) method of the [Storage Reference Object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference).

Try this:

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
    .subscribe(url => console.log(url))
```